# Inconsistent accessibility of c# windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public static TextBox t;
    public static TextBox t1;
    public static TextBox t2;
    public static TextBox t3;
    public static TextBox t4;
    public ServerPanel sp;
    public clientExplorer cE;

    public Form1()
    {



        InitializeComponent();
        t = textd;
        t1 = userName;

    }

    private void Server_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Server s = new Server(55552, 3, sp);
        Thread sthread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(s.startServer));
        sthread.Start();
        this.sp = new ServerPanel(s);

        sp.Show();//here we create the new form




        //while (!sthread.IsAlive)
        //    Thread.Sleep(1);

    }
```

it failes to compile due the problem mentioned above and i tried everything according to other peoples questions and nothing works.

```
public partial class ServerPanel : Form
{
    private  ListBox connectionlist { get; set; }
    private Server servero;
    // This delegate enables asynchronous calls for setting 
    // the text property on a TextBox control. 
    delegate void SetItemCallback(string text);
    public ServerPanel(Server s)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.servero=s;
        connectionlist = connected;

    }
```

i tried to make both the method constructor of ServerPanel and the Server property public but it didn't work

Comment: What are the other parts of the partial classes definitions like? And are you sure it's an exception, rather than failing to compile?

Comment: on which line you get the error?

Comment: i'm sorry its not an exception, its failing to compile/

Comment: And what's the error? It should tell you the field name that fails, or a line of code that's the problem.

Comment: the eror was that the constructor method is more accessible than the Server Class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your `Server` class is defined somewhere without the `public` access modifier.

Something like

```
class Server
{
    // ...
}
```

instead of

```
public class Server
{
    // ...
}
```

Using no access modifiers on class definitions has the same effect as declaring the class `internal`.

So `class Server` is the same as `internal class Server`.

You can read more about that in [Access Modifiers (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121(v=vs.90).aspx) and [Accessibility Levels (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba0a1yw2(v=vs.90).aspx).